# treeview control's TreeNodeCheckChanged event in asp.net is not firing after checking the checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

The `TreeNodeCheckChanged` event is not firing after the checkbox is checked.

```
Boolean flag;

protected void TreeView1_TreeNodeCheckChanged(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "check event fired";
    TreeView1.SelectedNode.Checked = true;
    if (flag)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode child in TreeView1.SelectedNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            child.Checked = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        TreeView1.SelectedNode.Checked = false;
        foreach (TreeNode child in TreeView1.SelectedNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            child.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After a little research, I found [that](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-classic/answers/619423-treeview-checkboxes-autopostback-ajax) : It seems to be what you want. :)

The code for the records :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
function postbackOnCheck() 
{ 
    var o = window.event.srcElement; 
    if (o.tagName == 'INPUT' && o.type == 'checkbox' && o.name != null && o.name.indexOf('CheckBox') > -1) 
        { __doPostBack("",""); } }  
</script>  
<asp:TreeView onclick="postbackOnCheck()" ID="treeContent"
runat="server"> ... And so on ... </TreeView>
```