# VB NET TreeNodeCheckChanged Event not working

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, treeview

I have a webform and I installed a treeview(system.web.ui.webcontrol.treeview) in this form. I would like that after I check the box it fire the event Treeview_TreeNodeCheckChanged but, this happening only after I hit the box and then hit the text.

```
Public Class TestFabio
Inherits Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    TreeView1.Nodes.Add(New TreeNode("Node 1"))
    TreeView1.Nodes(0).ChildNodes.Add(New TreeNode("NY"))
    TreeView1.Nodes(0).ChildNodes(0).ChildNodes.Add(New TreeNode("New York"))
    TreeView1.Nodes(0).ChildNodes(0).ChildNodes(0).ChildNodes.Add(New TreeNode("Flushing"))
    TreeView1.Nodes(0).ChildNodes(0).ChildNodes.Add(New TreeNode("boston"))
    TreeView1.Nodes.Add(New TreeNode("Node 2"))
End Sub

Private Sub TreeView1_TreeNodeCheckChanged(sender As Object, e As TreeNodeEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.TreeNodeCheckChanged
    MsgBox("test")
End Sub
```

End Class

[image]

So if I hit the checkbox doesn't happen nothing but, if I hit "New York" it does show up the message box!!! Somebody may help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [treeview control's TreeNodeCheckChanged event in asp.net is not firing after checking the checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146398/treeview-controls-treenodecheckchanged-event-in-asp-net-is-not-firing-after-che)

Comment: Yes look like same problem but that is C# and this is VB.... How can I convert in VB Net?

Comment: The answer is entirely in Javascript and should be usable as-is in your ASP page without any translation (based on my cursory reading of the answer and minimal experience with ASP).

Comment: Ok, I will try it and I will let you know

Comment: I'm sorry but doesn't working because Treeview from System.web.UI doesn't have onClick event!!! That's the problem

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not my area of expertise, so I don't have any further suggestions.

Comment: No problem thanks anyway